# Initial SelectedValue in DropDownList not posting back when re-selected

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I have a `DropDownList` with the following markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="ddlCampaignModule" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDynamicType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">None</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">Category Menu</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="11">Best Sellers</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="12">Best Reviews</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code behind I select the second option `Category Menu`. If I run my code and select any other option it posts back to `ddlDynamicType_SelectedIndexChanged` however if I re-select the second option (after selecting one of the other ones) my postback isn't triggered.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: In the code-behind, are you selecting the second option even on PostBack?

Comment: Oh $%&*. Can you post that as an answer please :) Long day ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are always selecting the 2nd option in the code behind, regardless of postback... ensure you only do that if it isn't!

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //select 2nd Item
}
```